# Comparing validity two measures in longitudinal data

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, independence, growth-model

I'm new to bigger data sets and modelling of longitudinal data, so I was wondering whether you could help me with the following problem:
I have 2 tests that are supposed to measure the same latent construct, however I have reason to doubt their validity. In my data set both tests were administered to a population at different time points and I would therefore like to compare the measures across time. I guess I could use multivariate growth models to estimating the relation between intercepts and slopes across constructs, but is it possible to take into account that the two measurements will not be independent for each individual?
Would it be possible to normalise the data and then take signed difference scores for each subject at each timepoint and fit a growth model to those scores? Or is there a better way of dealing with this data?

Comment: What do you mean by "validity" here? It is often used to mean whether a measurement actually measures what it purports to measure. I don't see how your situation would relate to that.

Comment: Well, it's not that important for the methodology, but you can imagine it as say a longitudinal study of intelligence with two different IQ measures. I would like to know:
1) whether the two measures are related as claimed (put here a bit colloquially as 'validity')
2) whether there are any patterns in how they change over time, i.e. do they become less discrepant once children enter school? Are they more closely related in children from high/low SES families etc.?
PS: This is not an IQ study - just an example of the data structure.